# php email not working?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to learn web development and right now I'm trying to do a contact form.

I couldn't get it to work so I googled it and found a page that said "Make sure php emailing even works. put this code in a new php file and open it"

```
    <?php
mail('mail1@mail.com','Test mail','The mail function is working!');
echo 'Mail sent!';
?>
```

I put my email into it and ran it. 
It prints the message on the web browser but when I check my email (inbox and spam folder) nothing is there.

How come I can't get these emails?

Comment: Do you have installed a Mail server like `Mercury`? If NOT installed and config one and come back if you still have a problem

Comment: No. I've just been sending it to my yahoo email to see if it would even send. Is that why its not working?

Comment: Simple question: You want to send a mail to mailadress xy. From where do you send it? ->You need a Mail server

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it's actually even going through

```
<?php
    if (mail('mail1@mail.com','Test mail','The mail function is working!')) {
        echo 'Mail sent!';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have a mail server installed. See the comments under OP's question if you haven't seen them already. We already know what the result will be; "`echo 'failed';`"